# apache mod rewrite - retrieveoriginal url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the apache httpd set up which redirects to tomcat.

Apache httpd runs on 9000 and tomcat runs on 8080 port in my local machine.

Below is my scenario

http://:9000/mypage?id=XYZ  must be redirected to Tomcat as http://:8080/myappp/mypage

I have set up mod_jk and load balancer which takes care of the routing to tomcat.
But I am not able to get the URL built correctly.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(XYZ)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1? [PT,L]

It is ok to store the mapping of "XYZ" to "myapp" hard coded in the rules.

I can get the query parameter using $1 , but how can I get the last portion of the original URL

Thanks

Comment: Use `%1` for a match in a `RewriteCond`, not `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the file name using the {REQUEST_FILENAME} . 
Thanks